# create Xml Document from Node

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net

Trying to create a new xml document from an existing xml node that is passed into a method. This with VB.NET. How to do ?

```
Private Shared Sub WriteChanges(parentNode As XmlNode, nodeName As String, m As Model.ModelBaseWithTracking)
    Dim xml As New XmlDocument()
    If parentNode.Name = "#document" Then
         'Need code here 
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This is simple. You can create nodes in the XML document as following:

```
Private Shared Sub WriteChanges(parentNode As XmlNode, nodeName As String, m As Model.ModelBaseWithTracking)
  Dim xml As New XmlDocument()
  If parentNode.Name = "#document" Then

    //To create root elemet
    Dim root As XmlElement = xml.CreateElement("document")
    xml.AppendChild(root)

    //To add child node to root element
     Dim child As XmlElement = xml.CreateElement("document1")
     root.AppendChild(child)

     child.SetAttribute("id", "1")

     //Add more nodes same as shown above..

  End If
End Sub
```